# Extract partial text from textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this text in textbox: `mytextvariable.mytext`

How to extract only text before the dot?

ex: textbox1 = mytext.text

Button Click

textbox2 = mytext without .text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var beforeDot = new String(textBox.Text.TakeWhile(c => c != '.').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use simple string manipulation:

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
int firstDot = text.IndexOf('.');
if (firstDot != -1)
{
    string firstPart = text.Susbtring(0, firstDot);
    textBox2.Text = firstPart;
}
else
{
    // Handle case with no dot
}
```

Fundamentally, this has nothing to do with the text coming from a textbox - it's just a string, really.

Comment: @Fulcrum: What do you mean? The part in the "if" statement extracts the part of the text before the dot, using the `firstDot` variable. You haven't said what you want to do if the text doesn't include a dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mytextvariable.mytext.Contains("."))
  String stuffBeforeTheDot = mytextvariable.mytext.Substring(0, mytextvariable.mytext.IndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Split" for this.

```
myText.Split('.').First();
```